# Is there file extension with = (equal, ASCII #3D) sign?

Tags: filenames, file-extension

Is there file extension with `=` (equal, ASCII #3D) sign?

Equal sign is not forbidden in FAT/NTFS, but I can't find any examples of Windows file extension with `=` sign (see [list](http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=%5E[%5EA-Z0-9])).

I need it to test my file name parsing routine.

Comment: Open up Windows File Explorer, left click on your test directory, create a new text file, change the extension to an extension with an equals sign, and test your code.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I was interesting, why this sign is not used. May be some restrictions here?

Comment: I suspect most people don't want to look up Windows extension rules, and use characters that they know are valid when creating a private or public extension.  I wouldn't have created .x=x if you hadn't asked this question.  :-)